# EasyTracker does not perform auto-tracking

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have the v3 SDK in the lib folder and the analytics.xml in the res/values folder.

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/#analytics-xml) it is stated that if I set `ga_autoActivityTracking` and `ga_reportUncaughtExceptions` to true, the EasyTracker will do auto tracking.

Needless to say that it does NOT do any auto tracking as there isn't any analytics code initialization.

What am I missing here? What's the trigger for performing auto-tracking?

Please don't tell me I need to write code in each activity to do this, as it will make the word **auto** redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please don't tell me I need to write code in each activity to do this,
>   as it will make the word auto redundant.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/#tracking-methods

Sorry, you need to add this to your activities. Obviously you can use inheritance and just add it to your base activity if you have one.

```
@Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ... // The rest of your onStart() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ... // The rest of your onStop() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
  }
```

Comment: Any idea how to "auto-track" fragments? Since the sidebar menu appeared, tracking activities isn't the way to go.